# How to prevent initialization of arrays of value types in C#?

Tags: c#

All arrays of any types in .NET are initialized to 0 by default (or null for reference types).
Is there any way to skip this initialization ? Just to save processor time. Say, i'm sure it will be initialized later again with different values:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Int32[] nums = new Int32[666];
    Array.ForEach(nums, n => rnd.Next());
```

Why should CLR init the nums array to zeros ? When its 666*4 bytes length, its ok. But when its 10^6 bytes ? so it clears 1M bytes without a need ?

Comment: are you running out of processor time?   clearing a million bytes doesn't take long,  if those nanoseconds are holding you back, I'd suggest C# isn't the right language for your application

Comment: just for reference, on my computer at least.... takes 50 ish microseconds to new int[10000000]  (10MB)

Comment: No, just want to findout how "deep" i can code with C# ? and maybe gurus know an answer. I'm sure, there is the ASM x86 instruction "rep stos"(b/w/d) involved, and its fast, but there no need. new int[10MB] is not

Comment: an example, there may be 1Gb of data, but, again - no need. Anyway i can allocate mem in C++ and use it.

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak: This is not C++.  Why are you allocating memory at all if you don't need it?

Comment: Stess test of C#, and my computer. Btw, found a strange thing - on single core, orderby(n => n) takes 21 seconds per 10^7 ints, but PLINQ on 2 cores, takes 7 seconds. 3 times faster ! but should be < 2

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with arrays.  Arrays simply initialize each element using `default(T)`.  If you have a value type then it must be constructed.  You cannot have a value type any other way, otherwise you would have a situation which is in direct violation of the semantic goals of value types.

I question whether or not this is actually a problem.  Have you profiled your code and determined that initialization of these arrays is a bottleneck?  I highly doubt it.  It certainly is not a bottleneck even in your example. Focus on solving real problems.

If you truly need such low level management then why in the world are you using C# to begin with?

Comment: Yes, in the code above its not a bottleneck, but, say in russian - korobit (don't know how in english), when we do unuseful things, what for ? why not leave it uninitialized, or just have a special word to mark it ? And, sorry, maybe i wrote incorrectly, i'm not a begginer, using C# about 7 years... Thanks

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak: Well you can't leave them uninitialized because it violated the spec.  Value types always have a value.  This is not C, this is C#.  I cannot imagine a real world scenario in which this would be a problem.  If you need that type of performance then you are using the wrong language.  I don't understand why anyone would worry about a perceived inefficiency that never causes an actual inefficiency in their code.

Comment: Btw, i'm sure, that in case of default(T) constructor, they do not call constructor, but init mem with zeros

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak: Well you simply cannot define an explicit parameterless constructor for a struct, so I'm not sure what they do.  What I do know is that this is not a real problem.

Comment: Ed S, u r right, i think as a C programmer, and i know a "fixed" and "safe" keywords in C#. And why not to add keyword like "pure" before/after/middle declaraion ?

Comment: @OlegSkripnyak: I understand, but this is not C, it's a completely different language semantically.  In C you don't pay for that which you do not need, but that was not a design goal for C#.

Comment: C# is changing everytime, in 3.0 there is linq, dynamic keyword in 4.0, but "var" keyword is where ? For fun, had to write this msg in linq

Answer (score 0):

If C# is anything like Java in this regard the clearing is a necessary feature.  If a reference array were not cleared then garbage collection would interpret the entries as valid pointers and go off the deep end.

Comment: Thanks, but as i think, GC in .NET do not bet on pointers in managed code, it has own pointers, in unmanaget code

Answer (score 0):

No way to avoid this, but you can avoid the default Int32 initialization by making your own value type (which can initialize from Random(), for instance).

Comment: "return 0;" Its abit different

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for dynamic allocation. This is not something you can do with arrays, but that would be doable with other dynamic allocation collections (such as lists). 
This is, however, **doesn't** mean that it's more performant. You are just deferring allocation until it's needed.

Comment: A list uses an array for storage anyway, and unless you give it a capacity up front it may have to resize some number of times.   I don't see how using a List could ever be more performant in any regard.

Comment: It's most certainly correct that arrays are more performant than lists, and I haven't said other than that! The question implies a wrong assumption about arrays, what Oleg was asking for is skipping allocation! which is not possible with arrays, however, you can defer allocation until it's needed, with that dynamic collection could give you a solution in expense of a sparse memory (performance!)

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I don't think it addresses the question in any way.  He says that he knows for a fact he will be allocating *N* objects in some array.  I don't think he's concerned with wasting space if he ends up not needing all of it.

Comment: I guess we disagree about answering the question, but (from your answer) we agree that the question may not be valid in the first place. That does not mean I am providing false or misleading facts in my answer. It's just approaching the problem from a different angle. However, I edited my answer to make sure it's not misinterpret.